# How to read from Sql Column To Spinner?

Tags: c#, android, sql, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to read an sql column and fill a Spinner. I'm using this code:

```
 var spinner1 = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.planets_spinner);
 var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem);
 spinner1.Adapter = adapter;

 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=192.168.1.101;Initial Catalog=RK1;user id=admin;password=1234");
 con.Open();

  SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM InventoryMainGroupItems where TaxOmada=0", con);

  SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
  while (sqlReader.Read())
  {
  adapter.Add("MainGroupItemName");

  }
  sqlReader.Close();
```

[image]

Comment: you need to use an ArrayAdapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an [`SpinnerAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) and assign it to your `Spinner`.

i.e. using an [`ArrayAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html):

```
var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem);
adapter.Add("First");
adapter.Add("Second");
var spinner1 = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.planets_spinner);
spinner1.Adapter = adapter;
```

`SQL.Net` Example:

```
string dbPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "myAppData.db3");
var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
db.CreateTable<Category>();

if (db.Table<Category>().Count() == 0)
{
    db.Insert(new Category()
    {
        Description = "First"
    });
    db.Insert(new Category()
    {
        Description = "Second"
    });
}

var categories = db.Table<Category>();
var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem);
foreach (var category in categories)
{
    adapter.Add(category.Description);
}
var spinner1 = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.planets_spinner);
spinner1.Adapter = adapter;
```

Comment: It Brings to me only the number of columns which exists in my table. But all with same name pls look my update above.

Comment: @user6453809 You are adding a static string over and over ` adapter.Add("MainGroupItemName");` change "MainGroupItemName" to your actual data source

Comment: My datasource is my ip right? I tried it but i get the same result

Comment: Error:Cannot Convert from object to string.

Comment: @user6453809 adapter.Add((string)sqlReader["TheTableColumnNameGoesHere"]);

Answer (score 0):

```
try
        {
            con.connect();// first you must connect to the database
            var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem);
            query = "select * from tbale_name";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con.DBConn);
            dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                adapter.Add("" + dataReader["column_name"].ToString() + "");
            }
            var spinner1 = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spn_spouseName);
            spinner1.Adapter = adapter;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
```

Comment: While this might be the answer, adding more comments and an explanation assist with understanding.

Comment: @static_cast yes next time i will add more comments and explanation